# combining MPI_Allgather and openmp parallel

Tags: mpi, openmp

I am trying to use a MPI_Allgather kind of functionality among openmp threads. That is all the threads will collectively have a copy a data(but each will generate only a part of it).

Infact by using the thread id in "tag" field of MPI_SEND and MPI_RECV, communication between openmp threads is possible. But MPI_Allgather does not seem to work that way.

### Example

I have 2 MPI process. Each process has 2 openmp threads. Now each of these 4 threads computes part of data. I want to use MPI_Allgather so that all threads combine their data and have a copy of the combined data. But it seems MPI_Allgather only works in the granularity of MPI processes.

I will appreciate any suggestions on how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you trying to write an OpenMP program (or routine) which operates like `mpi_allgather` or to understand how `mpi_allgather` works ?

Comment: I am using both openmp and MPI in a single program. Multiple processes and each process has multiple threads. Now I am trying to apply the MPI_Allgather across all of these processes/threads. That is each thread in each process will have a copy of the data after MPI_Allgather is executed. But it seems MPI_Allgather does not work like that. So I am looking for ways to do it.

Comment: BTW...using MPI_Send one can send data from thread i of process j to thread p of process q.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to explain more clearly what you want to learn.  Material in comment is often, rightly, ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MPI communication calls address entities called *ranks*. Currently all MPI implementations follow the interpretation that *rank* equals *OS process*, i.e. entities that in no way share memory space. That you can in principle address individual threads by crafting message tags is a work-around (or rather a hack) - e.g. try to implement the analogue of `MPI_ANY_TAG` for multiple threads without infinite loops and/or central process-wide dispatch mechanism.

There was a proposal in the early stages of MPI-3.0 to include the so-called *endpoints*, which is basically a mechanism that allows to distribute a set of ranks to a set of threads inside a process. The proposal didn't make it through the voting mechanism and the text has to be further refined.

That said, the following is a plausible way to achieve what you want without reimplementing the collective call with pt2pt operations:

```c
#pragma omp parallel shared(gbuf) private(buf,tid)
{
   tid = omp_get_thread_num();
   ...
   // Gather threads' data into the shared buffer 'gbuf'
   // Data should start at gbuf[rank * num_threads * data_per_thread]
   memcpy(gbuf + (rank*num_threads + tid)*data_per_thread,
          buf, data_per_thread*size);

   // Make sure all threads have finished copying their chunks
   // then gather the data from all the other ranks
   #pragma omp barrier
   #pragma omp single
   {
       MPI_Allgather(MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_TYPE_NULL,
                     gbuf, num_threads*data_per_thread, data_type, comm);
   }
   ...
}
```

It works by first gathering the data from each thread's local buffer `buf` into the global receive buffer `gbuf`. In this example a simple `memcpy` is used but it may be more involving if a complex derived datatype is being used. Once the local data is properly gathered, an in-place `MPI_Allgather` is used to collect the pieces from the other processes. The `single` construct ensures that only one thread per process would make the gather-to-all call.

If the number of threads is not the same in all processes, `MPI_Allgatherv` should be used instead.

Comment: Yes, I believe this should do it. There has to be one additional step -- after the MPI_Allgather call, I need to copy back the data from gbuf to the local thread buffers so that each thread has their own copy of the entire data and process it independently.